# How to install mypy-lang on python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-typing, mypy

The new version should support 2.7, but pip-installing it fails with a SyntaxError on a line with python 3 type-annotation syntax (which is kinda ironic):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
from mypy import git
  File "mypy/git.py", line 10
    def is_git_repo(dir: str) -> bool:
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't run Mypy on Python 2. The project's [README](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/v0.3.1/README.md#requirements) is specific about this:

> You need Python 3.2 or later to run mypy.

You [can still use it on Python 2 code](http://mypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-type-check-my-python-2-code) though. Just use the comment-based annotations and give Mypy the `--py2` flag. You also need the typing library for Python 2, which you can install using pip:

```
pip install typing
```